# Java projects aren't imported to IDE after update

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

###### Environment

- Operating System: openSUSE Leap 15.3
- JDK version: openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
- Visual Studio Code version: 1.71.2
- Java extension version: v1.10.0

###### Steps To Reproduce

1. F1 -> Java: Clean Java Language ...
2. Reload and delete

- [Sample project](https://github.com/olgapshen/VSCodeIssue)
- [Logs](https://github.com/olgapshen/VSCodeIssue/blob/main/client.log.2022-09-26)

###### Current Result

- Java Projects tab displays no projects, just "Import Projects" button
- No server log file availabe
- Configure Java Runtime page displays nothig, except "Refresh" button

###### Expected Result

Java project is imported to IDE

###### Additional Informations

Issue started after update to recent version.
Error from "Developer Tools":

> ERR ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/olga/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/a173b3b78960646b4119193930553375/redhat.java/jdt_ws/.metadata/.log': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/olga/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/a173b3b78960646b4119193930553375/redhat.java/jdt_ws/.metadata/.log'

**UPDATE**

Several new things.

First of all, I upgraded Gradle to 7.5.1 and successfully built the project with VSCode Gradle plugin.
The screenshot below.

Second I messed little button in bottom of the screen: "Lightweight mode", I pressed, and IDE tried to build the Java project, but with new errors.

I updated the logs in the repo:

- [Client log](https://github.com/olgapshen/VSCodeIssue/blob/main/client.log.2022-09-26)
- [Server log](https://github.com/olgapshen/VSCodeIssue/blob/main/.log)

[image: VSCode Gradle]

But unfortunately I still have the problem with Java project import.

Comment: I tried to open issue there: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/discussions/2697

Comment: "no such file or directory", well, I can understand that if it doesn't find the project, it won't open it

Comment: No, this is normal to delete home/olga/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/ folder. It is part of a troubleshooting. The IDE should handle this case.

Comment: and yet, it seems to give you trouble. it's being used somewhere, and can't be located

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I have an [answer](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2698#issuecomment-1258845512) from the support of the project on `GitHub`.
As [testforstephen](https://github.com/testforstephen) wrote:

> Looking at the logs you shared, it's exactly same as #2655 (comment) and microsoft/vscode-java-debug#1212.
> A quick workaround is to manually create a release file in your jdk home.

```bash
sudo sh -c 'echo "JAVA_VERSION=\"11.0.16.0\"" > /usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11/release'
```